# how to call lib.so from eclipse juno

Tags: java, android, eclipse

java and I have its own .so file, I made a new android project and I import the class.java and the so file under `lib\armeabi\lib.so` I tried to compile it but I got errors about **can't find the library**.

I did many searches and found to make a new so file. I have the header file and I gone to androidtools add native support and created empty cpp. I copied the header content to the cpp then in android.mk I matched the nessecary and then I compiled i am getting some errors

```
java.lang.UnsatisfiedLinkError: Couldn't load FXTEST from loader dalvik.system.PathClassLoader[dexPath=/data/app/com.example.fxtest-.apk,libraryPath=/data/app-lib/com.example.fxtest-2]: findLibrary returned null
```

I created `jni_onload` method and still got errors Any Idea? Let me know if you want some pictures, I will attach

Answer (score 0):

I suppose you might try to provide Java with the path to you native library with the following java option:

```
-Djava.library.path=/Path/To/You/File
```

I am not an android developer though, so I might be wrong.

Comment: actualy im facing a problem with native method...ignore the path issue..im getting an error saying..native method not found...how can i use native method? should i create jni on_load procedure?

Comment: I think this might be helpful: http://code.google.com/p/awesomeguy/wiki/JNITutorial